# Are all rank-1 positive semidefinite matrices the result of an outer product $vv^T$?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

If $v$ is a column vector in $\mathbb{R}^n$, then it is obvious that $V = vv^T$ is a rank-1 positive semidefinite matrix.  I am wondering if the converse is true: if $V$ is a square real rank-1 positive semidefinite matrix, can it be written in the form $vv^T$?

Comment: For future search'ability I wish to add that these self-outer products occur both in convex optimization and in quantum mechanics.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Hint:  consider an eigenvector ...

Comment: Ah, thanks.  So a rank-1 PSD matrix has exactly one nonzero eigenvalue, so the corresponding eigenvector ($v$) uniquely determines the system, so it must be equal to $vv^T$.  Cool!

Comment: Actually you want to take an eigenvector with  $\|v\| = \sqrt{\lambda}$.

Answer (score 10):

All rank one matrices are $w v^T,$ both nonzero and not required equal; if the vectors have the same number of entries the matrix is square. If square and symmetric, $w= \lambda v$ for a nonzero real number $\lambda.$ As in Robert's answer, if $\lambda > 0$ you get positive semidefinite, if $\lambda < 0$ you get negative semidefinite. In either case you can take $x = v \sqrt {|\lambda|}$ with the result that either $w v^T = x x^T$ or $w v^T = - x x^T.$